# Is there custom procedural import path in javascript intellisense in vscode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, firefox, intellisense

I want to make JS(ESM) intellisense for vscode in Firefox codebase for certain Firefox distribution.

In firefox, I have to register modules to build scripts like moz.build.
and imports like "resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm"
And that does not have autocompletion for that codes.
(This does not correspond to the directory structure one by one.)

I found jsconfig.json but that isn't dynamic.

Is there any way to do this?
Should I generate jsconfig.json that contains paths one by one?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how the Firefox build system works, yes, I think you'd probably have to generate a jsconfig.json or tsconfig.json and use some of the properties there to get what you want. Maybe [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths), or [`rootDirs`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDirs). Again, I don't know how the Firefox build system works, so that's the extent of what I can suggest.